# I can't play HTML5 video on some ios device (ipad and iphone)

Tags: cross-browser, video-streaming, html5-video, video.js, video-embedding

I have gone through practically every single stackoverflow question concerning this. I still having found an answer.
I was told to add `playsinline` and it should do the trick but still nothing. I use videojs and I assume it's practically the same thing as using a normal html5 embed video.
I have done all that could be done. Resetting network settings,adding playsinline,adding autoplay muted and loop, using 3 different browsers namely chrome, opera and safari. This works on some ios devices but not all no matter the browser. These are mp4 video formats.

```
<video-js class="vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" playsinline id="vid1"><source src="" type="video/mp4"></video-js>
```

This is practically how my code is. I do not know what else to do as this is really stressing me out in finding the answer. Please some angel help me out...

Comment: have you tried accessing the URL for the video directly in the browser to see if the encoding is supported? have you tried using just the plain `<video>...</video>` tag to eliminate library issues?

Comment: A URL to the video would be useful. Safari/iOS is particular about how video is delivered by the server, particularly range headers.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal hello. Yes I just did. It doesn't work. It doesn't go through no matter the browser. What do I do??

Comment: @misterben Seems like it. I just tried accessing the url and it doesn't work. How do I get it to send the proper range headers please?

Comment: if it's not playing with a direct link to the video then I'd look at how it's encoded - may simply not be supported

Comment: @Offbeatmammal It's encoded in H.264. That's the video codec. But why does this work on some ios devices only few it doesn't work? I even went to the apple store to test out and it worked on majority of devices but just few it didn't work on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright just to answer my own question.

I found out that when the attribute `preload='auto'` is used, ios devices/browsers load it a bit different from andriod phone.

Also this was inconsistent. It worked sometimes but majority of times it didn't.

After so many research, I was able to fix this by changing this to `preload='none'`.

I hope this would help someone else out...